# PHPMailer with Gmail API auth works with unlimited scope, does not work with limited scope

Tags: phpmailer, gmail-api

I am trying to set up a application that will use PHPMailer with Gmail API functionality.

I have written my program and tested it and it worked great. The last step for me was to see if I could make the system a bit more secure and follow best practices by only requesting the scope that is needed.

This version of the code works.

```
$params = [
        'clientId' => $clientKeys['clientID'],
        'clientSecret' => $clientKeys['secretKey'],
        'redirectUri' => $oauth2redirectURI,
        'accessType' => 'offline'
    ];

    $provider = new Google($params);
    $options = [
        'scope' => [
            'https://mail.google.com/'
        ]
    ];
```

However, when I reduce the scope to this:

```
$params = [
        'clientId' => $clientKeys['clientID'],
        'clientSecret' => $clientKeys['secretKey'],
        'redirectUri' => $oauth2redirectURI,
        'accessType' => 'offline'
    ];

    $provider = new Google($params);
    $options = [
        'scope' => [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
        ]
    ];
```

The initial authorization works to get the refresh token and such.

However, PHPMailer no longer is able to send any messages as that user.  Instead when attempting to send email messages, PHPMailer throws the following error:

`SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting1`

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and it should give you more info on why it is failing.

Comment: I found this while trying to debug:  `protected 'last_reply' => string '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b10-20020a170902bd4a00b00168b7d639acsm3396105plx.170 - gsmtp

' (length=184)`  but I am unsure why it would show that. It's like it's trying to use SMTP to log into google, when the thing clearly says `public 'AuthType' => string 'XOAUTH2' (length=7)`    Which implies that despite me telling it to use XOAUTH2 it's trying to do traditional SMTP credentials. (Which it doesn't have)

Comment: Perhaps another clue. `2022-06-12 21:52:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1nZXJkYXp-REDACTED-QEB
2022-06-12 21:52:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0d-REDACTED-8ifQ==
2022-06-12 21:52:21 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0d-REDACTED-8ifQ==
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`

Comment: When I went back and changed the scope to the FULL mail.google.com scope, here is the debug output, and it works just fine. `2022-06-12 22:06:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [211.108.12.52]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-06-12 22:06:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1nZXJkYXp-REDACTED-2sBAQ==
2022-06-12 22:06:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
2022-06-12 22:06:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<user@gmail.com>`

Comment: That error message is just Google’s way of saying auth failed, nothing to do with an actual password.

Comment: Did you delete the application token and re-auth after changing the scopes?

Comment: Yes Indeed I did revoke the token in Gmail security before re-creating the token.